# VBA / ADO QUERY Runs on my computer and fails on coworkers computer

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado

The following code works perfectly fine on my computer. I cannot understand why it's not working on another persons computer. Can someone lead me towards ideas that may help trouble shoot this?
The error (with on error commented out) is that the array isn't being loaded with data. Get an error like "either bof or eof is true for the current record"

Also I can tell you if the on error GoTo NEXTT is left on.. it goes there and tries to erase the array and returns a wrong data type error. Makes me think the array is empty.

I checked Conn.State and I can confirm that the connection is open.

```
Function sbADO(ban_id, upc_id, div_id)
'Must add Activex data objects libaray 2.8
Dim sSQLSting As String
On Error GoTo nextt

Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String



DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName

'You can provide the full path of your external file as shown below


sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DBPath _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Conn.Open sconnect
sSQLSting = "SELECT * From [data$] where BANNER_ID IN (" & ban_id & ") AND UPC_ID IN (" & upc_id & ") AND DIVISION_ID IN (" & div_id & ") " 'Your SQL Statemnt (Table Name= Sheet Name=[DataSheet$])

    mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn
        '=>Load the Data into an array
        ReturnArray = mrs.GetRows
                ''OR''
        '=>Paste the data into a sheet
        'Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset mrs
    'Close Recordset
    mrs.Close

'Close Connection
Conn.Close

'
Exit Function
nextt:
Erase ReturnArray
'mrs.Close
Conn.Close
    'MsgBox (ReturnArray(6, 2)) '(feild, row)

End Function
```

Comment: since you use early binding, does the other coworker have the ADO reference checked in the VBE > Tools > Reference?

Comment: How does it fail?  Error messages?  No results?

Comment: "Not working" is not a useful description of the actual problem.

Comment: The Array doesn't seem to loading anything so I an an error something to the effect of either bof or eof is true or the current record

Comment: yes the other coworkers have the same things checked that I do in their references window.

Comment: Not checked, installed createobject will still do without references, dim x as new adodb.recordset wont work if not checked.  Does no criteria work, i.e. select * from xyz

Comment: After opening the recordset you need to check for `mrs.EOF` - if that's `True` then you got no results from your query

Comment: I can tell you if the on error GoTo NEXTT is not commented out.. it goes there and tries to erase the array and returns a wrong data type error. Makes me think the array is empty.

Comment: Confirmed, it's not loading data into the array. But I don't know why not! Tried @Nathan_Sav suggestion just simple select * from without parameters but same issue remains.

Comment: Would this have anything to do with the fact that I have admin access on my machine and the others do not?

Comment: ITS BECAUSE THE DISTRIBUTED FILE IS READ ONLY...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because 
DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName <-- the workbook is set to read only. 
Removing read only status fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using ADO to query data in the *same* workbook? That might be for the purposes of simplifying this problem for SO, but it would be easier and faster to get the array you need by referring to the range directly. But in this answer, I'll assume that you really do want to use ADO.

You're trying to use ADO to open the workbook, but you're not specifying the ConnectionString or Open methods with any read-only arguments. Try making these adjustments:

```
'Add Mode=Read

sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DBPath & _
";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";Mode=Read;"

'Add adLockReadOnly
mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn, , adLockReadOnly
```

Comment: I am still getting the same errors after making your prescribed changes. any ideas?

Comment: Are you by chance having me set everything to READ ONLY? I think I need the exact opposite.

Comment: If the file is read only, then the only access you can have (and the only access you need, given your SQL) is Read Only, and you'll need to specify that explicitly. I had thought that I'd specified the correct ConnectionString parameter, but maybe there's an Excel-specific Read only name-value-pair...

Comment: The above works when the file is NOT set to read only. I must make it read only. However, I think the connection needs write permission to fill the array. (or so it seems).  Basically I have data on SHEET1 and I want to use ADO SQL to write data from SHEET1 into an ARRAY.. it works when file is NOT read only .. and fails when file is set to READ ONLY. I am so confused why this is happening.

Comment: Why would a connection require Write permissions to Read data? ADO is trying to open the connection with read and write, but can't because the file is read only (and open already), but you should be able to make the connection work read-only as you're not writing any data.

Comment: that makes sense.  Thank you for helping to explain. I did some testing. It works when not set to "read only" mode even though it's open already. Even more strange, it works also in read only as long as the only reason it's read only is because another user is in the file. Do you know why this is? How can I stop ADO from failing due to asking for Write permission?